# Laravel vs PHP query database query execution time

Tags: php, laravel, execution

I have been executing the following query using LARAVEL's ORM Eloquent, "normal" PHP, and also PHPmyuAdmin raw SQLand have surprising execution tilme differences , NOT in favor of LARAVEL, which I find very surprising, so I'm wondering if  / what I'm not doing things correctly in LARAVEL

Laravel query :

```
$words=Word::select('id','mot_origine')->where ('origine','fr')->get();
```

Execution time : **14.265946865082 sec** !!

"Pure PHP" query :

```
$statement = "SELECT id_mot, mot_origine, genre FROM dico WHERE origine='fr'";
$words = $this->query($statement);
```

Execution time : 0.25629806518555 sec

PHPMyAdmin Execuction time : 0,0009 second(s).

For a total of 7 803 items ...

Comment: Which table does the model `Word` refer to? Seems like you are selecting from different tables

Comment: You can use `->toSql()` in Laravel to print out the query used. Rerun the same query in PHP and phpMyAdmin

Comment: @Techno: You are right I the wWord model refers to a different table, but the data is the same exactly : it''s just the "iD"'s name that changes from the "id_mot" name to the more "laravel-compliant" "id" ...Hopwevber the rest of the dat a& table is structured exactly in the same way eg; "id"  & "id_mot" are both primary keys for the table

Comment: @user2955335 also no other indexes?

Comment: @bromber:I get the following :
"select `id`, `mot_origine` from `dico` where `origine` = ?"
Which looks identical to the "pure PHP" query ..

Comment: Did you install composer packages like debugbar?

Comment: @techno:
No no other indexex, I'll re-install debugbar , good idea...